# How can I generalise this "fill-x-canvasses" code?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write a function that fills canvasNum amount of canvasses with a background colour. Each canvas will be named sequentially (knobCanvas1, knobCanvas2, knobCanvas3 etc.). Context: I'm making some GUI knobs to control some parameters in a web application, and drawing them on several canvasses.

This is some of my knobs.js:

```
function initKnobs(canvasses)
{
    canvasNum = canvasses;
}

function drawKnobs()
{
    //draw background for <canvasNum> canvasses
    var knobBGCanvas = document.getElementById("knobCanvas1");
    var knobBGContext = knobBGCanvas.getContext("2d");
    knobBGContext.fillStyle = "#333333";
    knobBGContext.fillRect(0, 0, knobBGCanvas.width, knobBGCanvas.height);

    if(canvasNum > 1)
    {
        knobBGCanvas = document.getElementById("knobCanvas2");
        knobBGContext = knobBGCanvas.getContext("2d");        
        knobBGContext.fillStyle = "#333333";
        knobBGContext.fillRect(0, 0, knobBGCanvas.width, knobBGCanvas.height);
    }
    if(canvasNum > 2)
    {
        knobBGCanvas = document.getElementById("knobCanvas3");
        knobBGContext = knobBGCanvas.getContext("2d");
        knobBGContext.fillStyle = "#333333";
        knobBGContext.fillRect(0, 0, knobBGCanvas.width, knobBGCanvas.height);
    }
    if(canvasNum > 3)
    {
        knobBGCanvas = document.getElementById("knobCanvas4");
        knobBGContext = knobBGCanvas.getContext("2d");
        knobBGContext.fillStyle = "#333333";
        knobBGContext.fillRect(0, 0, knobBGCanvas.width, knobBGCanvas.height);
    }
    if(canvasNum > 4)
    {
        knobBGCanvas = document.getElementById("knobCanvas5");
        knobBGContext = knobBGCanvas.getContext("2d");
        knobBGContext.fillStyle = "#333333";
        knobBGContext.fillRect(0, 0, knobBGCanvas.width, knobBGCanvas.height);
    }
    if(canvasNum > 5)
    {
        knobBGCanvas = document.getElementById("knobCanvas6");
        knobBGContext = knobBGCanvas.getContext("2d");
        knobBGContext.fillStyle = "#333333";
        knobBGContext.fillRect(0, 0, knobBGCanvas.width, knobBGCanvas.height);
    } 

    <actually draw the knobs>
}
```

So in the main program we call

```
initKnobs(x);
```

then

```
drawKnobs();
```

and it should fill x canvasses with a grey background.

The problem is that this is not a general solution, what if we want to use 7 canvasses?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to pass either a list of element ID's or a NodeList into the function to make it wholly reusable and iterate over that list.

```
/**
 * @param {NodeList} nodes
 */
function drawKnobs(nodes) {
    var currentContext;

    for(var i = nodes.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        currentContext = nodes[i].getContext("2d");
        currentContext.fillStyle = "#333333";
        currentContext.fillRect(0, 0, nodes[i].width, nodes[i].height);

        // <actually draw the current knob (nodes[i]) 
    }
}

var myKnobs = document.querySelectorAll("#knobCanvas1, #knobCanvas2, #knobCanvas3, #knobCanvas4, #knobCanvas5, #knobCanvas6");
drawKnobs(myKnobs);
```